# Is wordpress too heavy for basic site with little content

Tags: wordpress

Apologies if this has already been asked, couldn't seem to find a good answer. I am building a website which really isn't going to be content rich. The site will have sections and sub-sections which can easily be organised as menu items based on a folder and file name structure. Therefore more menu items will mean more folders or files. I've used wordpress a few times but find it very heavy and packed with things that I dont use and to top it all of there are soo many hidden elements in it that you don't know about.

It seems like a real waste loading so much libraries and content and hidden links just to install a theme and customise it. I could do a very basic CMS with file-structure driven menu tree with mod-rewrite

Comment: This is primarily opinion-based, so this should be closed. To answer you directly, there are many lighter options than Wordpress. Home-growing your own is always good experience, but you need to be extremely careful with not opening your application up to security holes. [Grav](https://getgrav.org/) is pretty light. You can also wire together your own base set of packages using [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/). There are many options at your disposal. Pick one that fits your use-case.

Comment: Nope it's not too heavy. But it depends on your need. You also coud have a lithger cms with php frameworks like laravel. Take a look at it : https://github.com/ozdemirburak/laravel-5-simple-cms. But wordpress has a good UI to add page, images, and if someday you want new features you can add plugins or code stuff by yourself. It's quite easy.

Comment: Maybe a question for the wordpress stack exchange, but it comes down to content. If you will be changing and update content frequently a cms is a good idea. As for wordpress... its well supported and receives updates frequently so that is a plus.

Comment: @maiorano84 don't knew it, i'm gonna test right now !